# Add one column of 2D array to listbox using AddRange

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, listbox, addrange

I have one 2D array:

```
string[,] table = new string[100,2];
```

and I want to add the table[,0] to a listbox, something like that

```
listbox1.Items.AddRange(table[,0]);
```

What is the trick to do that?

Edit: I want to know if it possible to do that using AddRange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For readability you can create extension method for an array.

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static T[] GetColumn<T>(this T[,] array, int columnNum)
    {
        var result = new T[array.GetLength(0)];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            result[i] = array[i, columnNum];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now you can easily add ranges as slices from array. Note that you create a copy of elements from original array.

```
listbox1.Items.AddRange(table.GetColumn(0));
```

Comment: I just interest how I can add first column of 2d array to a listbox using AddRange function

Comment: so i can do it only by making my own function... ok thank you

Comment: yes, there is nothing build in `.net` for this purposes. But you can use jagged arrays, which are essentially arrays of arrays, which in your canse would be `string[][]`. Then accessing `table[2]` will return to you the second row.